# Using PHP for random hour functions

Tags: php

How do I `file_put_contents('time.txt', time());` on random hour (using 1 to 9 minutes delay)?

Example: on `00:01`, `00:05`, `00:06`, `00:15`.

I want to use `crontab` to run the PHP script.

Comment: What is the point of this? Why does it have to happen at random intervals?

Comment: Question: is the time suppose to be random or the occurrence of the script is what is random

Comment: The `file_put_contents` function was just for an example. The main idea of the script is to create a blog post between few minutes or hours, depends on the available pending posts in the database. Thank you for the help, I'm testing it now.

Comment: I'd approach this completely the other way around: Tag each blog post randomly with a time when it's supposed to be released, and alter your blog program accordingly to show only released posts. Or make an algorithm that dynamically decides how many entries to show based on some criteria. I would certainly not do this by actually running cron jobs which need to change data in "realtime".

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
if (mt_rand(0, 5) == 0) {
    file_put_contents('time.txt', time());
}
```

Set this as a cron job to execute every minute. It'll fire randomly about 1 out of 6 times on average. Increase or decrease the numbers as needed.